# Devops Pipeline not installing Playwright correctly

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, playwright

I am trying to create a Devops Pipeline to deploy to a Python Azure Function App. Using Vs code I can successfully deploy to the function app and everything works 100%. I had to add 2 app settings mentioned here (https://github.com/anthonychu/20220303-python-func-playwright) to get it working.

Next steps was to create a Pipeline in Azure Devops. I tried using the classic editor and the YAML creator but I just cant get Playwright to install. I keep getting the error:
*Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated. Please run the following command to download new browsers: playwright install <3 Playwright Team.*

Anyone here managed to get a Devops pipeline to deploy to a Python Azure Function App V2 that includes Playwright to work yet?

Basically I need to figure out how to run playwright install chromium as a post build task. I tried adding a POST_BUILD_COMMAND app setting but it doesn't seem to run when I deploy using the Pipeline, its does however run when deploying using VS Code

My current YAML:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: "Set Python version to 3.10"
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.10'
    architecture: 'x64'

- bash: |
    if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
    then
        dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
    fi
    pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

- bash: |
    sudo mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot
    PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/home/site/wwwroot
    python -m pip install playwright
    PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/home/site/wwwroot /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/bin/python3.10 -m playwright install chromium
  displayName: 'Install Playwright'


- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

Comment: It's always painful to deploy playwright browsers. It may be worth considering a hosted-playwright solution like BrowserCat, where your code can connect remotely.

Comment: Have you added `playwright` in your `requirements.txt`? If you have, there is no need to install playwright again. Would you please try to deploy your function app on your local machine [using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli) and check what's the result.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT yes playwright is already added in the requirement.txt but Playwright also requires that you run the command "playwright install" on the OS. So when deploying using VS Code it runs this command as part of the Post build app settings I specified, but when deploying from Devops its not running the Post Build command as I assume Devops deploys using the RunFromZip option and not ZipDeploy

Comment: @Dinerz, I have shared the detailed steps to install playwright and chromium. You can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a yaml pipeline from the template:
   [image]
2. Use the following scripts to install chromium in the yaml pipeline.

```
    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
        cd ./.python_packages/lib/site-packages
        python -m playwright install chromium 
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
      env:
        PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH: $(workingDirectory)
```

3. Add an app setting `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/home/site/wwwroot` in the function app.
   [image]
4. Then the function works as shown below.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I am running a jenkins piple line and I use the Playwright image instead. I am quoting the [Playwright documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker). I am using the Jammy image myself in my pipeline

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.41.1-jammy
```

Have you tried that? That could be a potential solution and you won't have to hunt for the right version of chromium and install it. This comes preinstalled with Playwright browsers.